# Arara integration in Emacs?

Tags: auctex, latex, arara

Is there a way to integrate [Arara](https://github.com/cereda/arara) as a way to automate the building process of a LaTeX document in Emacs/AUCTex?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the appropriate entry to [`TeX-command-list`](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002dcommand_002dlist).  Insert the following code in your init file:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
        '("Arara" "arara --verbose %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t :help "Run Arara.")))
```

The `--verbose` flag [has been suggested](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/9715/620?noredirect=1#comment72768_9718) by Paul Stanley.

Comment: Better `("Arara" "arara --verbose %s" TeX-run-Tex nil t :help "Run Arara.")` The `--verbose` flag allows auctex to parse the output and avoids spurious errors.

Comment: Once I've added this code to my init file, how do I run it? `C-c C-a`?

Comment: `C-c C-c Arara RET` should work