# Why does AucTeX say I need to run LaTeX again, when in fact I don't need to do so?

Tags: auctex

I've used the solution suggested in [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/50371/4084) to automize the compilation of my LaTeX document using Arara upon entering `C-c C-a`. The resulting output is perfect, but the following erroneous message appears in the Emacs status bar: `You should run LaTeX again`. When I run `arara` on the same LaTeX document from the command line (not within Emacs), I get no such message.

Why is this message displayed? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: My guess: Because you're running under arara, you get the output of every latex run in the same output buffer, which auctex then searches for indications that a new run is needed. You could try setting `TeX-parse-all-errors` til `nil` and see if the problem goes away. There is a price to be paid for that, however, since you now lose some of the debugging features of auctex.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: Thanks. How can I test this theory? Where does AucTeX look for the arara output?

Comment: If you want to see the code that does the parsing, look at the function `TeX-LaTeX-sentinel`. But really, it seems the first thing to do is to turn off `TeX-parse-all-errors` as I suggested. You can do it interactively with `M-x set-variable`, and see if it cures your problem – and what the side effects may be. If you want to make this fix permanently, put `(with-eval-after-load 'tex-buf (setq TeX-LaTeX-sentinel nil))` in your emacs init file.